# The performance of Ubuntu installed by wubi

Tags: performance, ubuntu, wubi

As you know, we can install the Ubuntu desktop by using wubi, in my opinion, it should be the same as other virtual machine, but I want to know the drawback about performance, has anyone done any benchmarks to quantify the performance? We can just ignore the performance drawback, or the loss is seriously, especial the IO performance?

Comment: This question has already been asked before -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/8159/wubi-performance-difference

Comment: Anecdotal and un-scientific evidence here: Having tried Wubi 12.04 on win7 laptop, I noticed significantly slower behavior doing normal tasks like copying files or extracting from archives. Not only that but while performing any file I/O it seemed to cause lockups/slowdowns in all other running applications, meaning it was impossible to multi-task. CPU usage was fluctuating in system monitor, and memory usage was very low the whole time. Nearly same behavior between Unity and Unity 2D interfaces in my opinion.

Comment: I installed ubuntu 12.04 with wubi on windows 7, there was lag when moving mouse cursor during installation of softwares